# How can I add the Stripe customer id to the user's data in firestore using cloud functions?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

What I'm trying to do is create a stripe customer when a new user signs up, then update the user's data in Firestore with the Stripe customer ID. I'm creating the stripe customer, but for some reason I'm not retrieving the stripe customer ID and updating the user's data. Below is my code. Looking for some help!

```
//create Stripe customer-------------------------------------------------------------
    exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.firestore
    .document('customers/{customerId}')
    .onCreate(async (doc, context) => {
      
      const stripe = require('stripe')(functions.config().stripe.testkey)

      const userData = doc.data()
      
      const customer = {
        email: userData.email,
        phone: userData.phone,
        name: userData.firstName+" "+client.lastName,  
      }
      
      let cust = null
      
      try {
        cust = await stripe.customers.create(customer)
        .then(async () => {
          const stripeCustomer = await cust
          if (stripeCustomer) {
            const stripeInfo = {
              customerId: stripeCustomer.id
            }         
            try {
               admin.firestore().collection('cusomters').doc(userData.userId)
                  .update({
                      stripeInfo
                  })
              //await snap.ref.update({ stripeInfo })
            } catch (err) {
              console.error(err)
            }
          }
        })
      } catch (err) {
        return err
      }
      return cust
    
      
    })
```

Comment: are you getting error?

Comment: @DivyaniYadav no, which is leaving me perplexed... I'll try a different approach

Comment: @DivyaniYadav I found a spelling error lol... we'll see what happens

Comment: Is the stripe customer getting created? What part is failing? Also I'm unclear why you're using a pattern mixing await and .then() when creating the customer: `cust = await stripe.customers.create(customer)
        .then(async () => {
          const stripeCustomer = await cust` what is going on here?

Comment: @AntonySanders can you correct that collection('cusomters') to 'customers' and see whether is it working fine or not?

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify your async/await/promise structure used here:

```
cust = await stripe.customers.create(customer)
        .then(async () => {
          const stripeCustomer = await cust
```

why the `await` and `.then()` with another `await`? This is really unclear.

Second, your collection has a typo: `collection('cusomters')` misspells `customers` so maybe this ends up working but in a different place than you expect?